# I have a bow, what am I?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> I have a bow, but no set of strings
> I have a collar, but I'm not a pet thing
> I have a stem, but I'm not from a pot
> I have a blade, just not from Camelot
> I am often scraped and dropped and abused
> But not unkindly, I have my own use
> I open what is precious, expensive or dear
> Except for a pick, there is nothing to fear!

What am I?

(Hint:

> This should tell all, I swing off a wall
>  Or end of a string, or inside a ring)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe the answer is

> A Key!

Explanation:

> **I have a bow, but no set of strings**
>  The bow of a key is the (usually) round bit you hold.
>
>  **I have  a collar, but I'm not a pet thing**
>  Some older keys have collars, which is a ring around the shaft to stop the key inserting too far.
>
>  **I have a stem, but I'm not from a pot**
>  The stem, AKA shaft is the long cylindrical part.
>
>  **I have a blade, just not from Camelot**
>  Newer keys have a blade (the ridged part).
>
>  **I am often scraped and dropped and abused**
>  Keys are probably one of the least looked-after items.
>
>  **But not unkindly, I have my own use**
>  Keys are useful to open locks.
>
>  **I open what is precious, expensive or dear**
>  People often lock away their valuables with a key.
>
>  **Except for a pick, there is nothing to fear!**
>  Locks are perfectly secure, except for lock picks...

Hints:

> **This should tell all, I swing off a wall**
>  People often hang keys on a hook on the wall.
>
>  **Or end of a string, or inside a ring)**
>  People can carry keys on a string or on a keyring

Comment: Wonderful! Hopefully that wasn't too easy?

Comment: I wouldn't have gotten it from the first four lines, but the last two gave it away for me! I had to check to see if the first four actually fit.